# CreateIdentityAsync, RavenDb.AspNet.Identity. Exception: UserId not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, ravendb

I've seen the other questions in this topic, but it seems that I'm missing something out that I can't find from the other questions. Maybe it's related to RavenDb.AspNet.Identity. Anyway I can't see where in my code I do wrong.

When I Register a user. All goes fine in saving a `IdentityUserByUserName` and a `ApplicationUser` to RavenDb. But when it goes to Login the User at `await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);`
 something goes wrong. and throws the error: "UserId not found".

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
           // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in   CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
           var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
           // Add custom user claims here

           return userIdentity;
        }
    }

        //from AccountController start
        [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Id = "RavenDbUsers/" + model.Email };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            await AsyncDataSession.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
    //from AccountController end


    public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
       public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
            : base(userManager, authenticationManager) 
       {
       }

       public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
       {
          return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
       }

       public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
       {
          return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
      }
  }
```

UPDATE:

//ctor, SingInManager, UserManager of Controller

```
        private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public AccountController()
    {
        _userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(() => AsyncDataSession));
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

//UPDATE: ApplicationUserManager

```
    public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
            : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var session = context.Get<IAsyncDocumentSession>();
        session.Advanced.UseOptimisticConcurrency = true;

        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(session));
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        manager.UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        manager.DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        manager.MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
```

Comment: Did you figure out the problem? Just following up from our conversation earlier this week.

Comment: Yes I finally did! At the line "var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync" in the controller, the user was saved to db. But I think, like you said first, my UserManager and SignInManager used different sessions. So after that line, I had to manually store and save the user using my base raven controller session. Then SignInManager could find the user in db(same session). So I think it was a mistake by me... Many thanks for the help and the code you shared. It helped me find the problem

Comment: Glad to help. Feel free to reach out if you have any RavenDB Identity issues at all. I'm @judahgabriel on Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of RavenDB.AspNet.Identity here.

When you get to this line, what is the value of user.Id?

```
await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
```

Also, can you verify the user actually exists in the database before that code is executed?

My psychic debugging skills tell me your UserManager may be using a different IAsyncDocumentSession than accountController.AsyncDataSession, and thus, the user isn't actually in the database when you make the SignInAsync call.

Comment: Hi! When I get to that line, user.Id is what I assign it to (eg."RavenDbUsers/mymail@mail.com"). I can also verify that user exists in the db. By the way, thanks for a great project! But I don't know what to do here really...something in my implementaion must be wrong...

Comment: Just to confirm, the user exists in the DB *before* SignInAsync is actually executed, yes?

Comment: Iv'e updated my question with ctor, SingInManager, UserManager of the AccountController if that might be a clue

Comment: Can you show us the code for ApplicationUserManager.Create? (Usually resides in IdentityConfig.cs)

Comment: Updated with ApplicationUserManager.Create

Comment: OK, that all looks good, and I have similar code working for TwinCitiesCodeCamp.com. If it helps, my working code is at https://github.com/JudahGabriel/twincitiescodecamp/tree/master/TwinCitiesCodeCamp Could you send me the source code, or a simply repro case? judahgabriel at gmail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133832/discussion-between-judah-himango-and-user3228992).